# Aggregate 3 table retreiveing full data of one

Tags: mysql

I've already resolved, thanks to @RolandoMySQLDBA, a great part of this aggregation of 3 tables as shown on the link

[old state of question with sqlfiddle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84824/how-to-get-the-sum-with-more-then-one-table/84832#84832)

But I want to display whole rows of tblb even if it's not within the range of date. As  in the link, cacao is not displayed but it's in data of tblb.

Is it possible ? Using another method such Union etc.. ?

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8459/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use LEFT join when joining tableb and tablec - in that case all records from tableb will be included.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8459/7)